# How to make data frame from python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python dictionary in below format.

```
dict={'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':[7,8,9]}
```

how to create a data frame such that

```
a b c-----> column names or feature names
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to call you `dict` with `dict` variable because you shadowed built-in type and constructor `dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call the `DataFrame` constructor:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

Comment: hmm...how i missed this..i am using it as pd.DataFrame([dict])...which causing the issue....Thank you David